# Make checkbox options 1 and option 2 required but make option 3 optional

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a checkbox with 3 options (option 1, option 2, and option 3). In Javascript, I would like option 1 and option 2 to be required, if either option is selected, then the other is no longer required. Option 3 is always optional. Any ideas?

I've tried the following:

```
    if ($('input[value="0"]', this).is(':checked') ||
    $('input[value="1"]', this).is(':checked')) {
    // everything's fine...
} else {
    this.elem.find('input[value="0"]').prop('required', true);
    this.elem.find('input[value="1"]').prop('required', true);
    this.elem.find('input[value="2"]').prop('required', false);
}
```

and this (my thought was if nothing is selected then option 1 and 2 is required; ignoring the third option completely):

```
if ($myCheckbox.length === 0) {
  $myCheckbox.elem.find('input[value="0"]').attr('required', 'required');
  $myCheckbox.elem.find('input[value="1"]').attr('required', 'required');
} else {
  $myCheckbox.elem.find('input[value="0"]').removeAttr('required');
  $myCheckbox.elem.find('input[value="1"]').removeAttr('required');
}
```

and even something like this based on another dropdown:

```
    $myCheckbox.elem.find('input[value="0"]').prop('required', $myDropdown.isSelected());
    $myCheckbox.elem.find('input[value="1"]').prop('required', $myDropdown.isSelected());
```

but nothing works. What happens is that first two options are not being shown as required. Users can still submit my answers without touching the checkbox. Users cannot submit anything until either option 1 or option 2 is selected from a checkbox with 3 options

Comment: *but nothing works*; what *does* happen? Are there any errors in your dev console?

Comment: Aside from the issue it sounds more like option 1 and option 2 should be radio buttons, not checkboxes

Comment: @mykaf _but nothing works_ meaning the first two options are not being shown as required. I can still submit my answers without touching the checkbox. Users cannot submit anything until either option 1 or option 2 is selected from a checkbox with 3 options.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought about using radio buttons but I still needed option 3 to be optional. My thought with radio buttons is that only 1 option can be selected regardless, right?

Comment: this in not a problem about required options, this a problem about validation. you are in a wrong understanding way

Comment: @MisterJojo Oh okay, I didn't think of it that way. How would this scenario work for validation in javascript?

Comment: If  and 2 are radios, option 3 could still be a checkbox.

Comment: I added my answer. would you have a comment on it?

Answer (score 1):

How about the HTML `required` attribute?

```js
function myFunction(){
  document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(function(element){
    //element.checkValidity();
    element.reportValidity()
  })
}
```

```html
<label>
en
<input type=radio name=language required>
</label>
<label>
fr
<input type=radio name=language required>
</label><br>
<input type=checkbox>

<button onclick=myFunction()>check validity</button>
```

Comment: with a radio button both options can't be checked

Comment: Okay, I see what you were doing here, and this is definitely another route to go that I know for sure will work. I actually had this type of plan as a backup already, but I am just wondering if there was a way to do this without using radio buttons and only checkboxes in javascript?

Comment: Seems like your questions is radio vs checkbox? https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#radio-button-state-(type=radio)

Answer (score 0):

this is a question about validation

sample code:

```js
const
  myForm      = document.querySelector('#my-form')
, errOpts_1  = 'choose one between option 1 or option 2 ( or both )'
  ;
myForm.oninput =_=>
  {
  myForm.option_1.setCustomValidity('');
  console.clear();
  }
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  console.clear();
  
  if (!myForm.option_1.checked && !myForm.option_2.checked)
    {
    myForm.option_1.setCustomValidity(errOpts_1);
    myForm.option_1.reportValidity();

    e.preventDefault();  // disable submit.
    }

  console.log('the form is valid')
  e.preventDefault();  // only in test disable submit.
  }
myForm.onreset =_=>
  {
  myForm.option_1.setCustomValidity('');
  console.clear();
  }
```

```css
label { display: block; margin: 1em; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<form id="my-form" action="#">
  <label title="required if option 2 is not checked">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option_1">
    option 1 
  </label>
  <label title="required if option 1 is not checked">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option_2">
    option 2 
  </label>
  <label> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="option_3"> 
    option 3 
  </label>
  
  <button>submit</button>  <button type="reset">reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I like the route you chose and this is something I am going to try. I will try this out and get back.